# Flurry Analytics Dashboard -- Display Duration of Timed Events

Tags: analytics, flurry

On the Flurry Dashboard, is there a way to compare the total duration of 2 (or more) different timed events?

For example, suppose an application logs distinct timed events for different screens (i.e. Screen1, Screen2, Screen3, etc.) starting the timed event when the screen appears and ending the timed event when the screen disappears.  We would like a way to visually compare the total amount of time for each of the events on a single graph of some sort.  (We would also like to see the average total amount of time per session on a single graph)  This would give us a quick understanding of what percentage of time our users are spending on different screens within the app.

I've played with the dashboard but I can't seem to find a way to do this.  It seems like it is not possible to show the duration of timed events on the dashboard.  So the only way to view event duration is to look at individual events in isolation in the Events section.

Hopefully I'm missing something, so thanks in advance for any answers to this question.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I've also faced that problem, i've created some timed events, start & end the timed event, i can see the events with names, associated user id and their parameters, but unfortunately event duration graphics shows no data :(

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find a solution.  I believe I asked Flurry about this in their last annual survey, but this is still a missing feature that would be useful to me.

Comment: So than it seems that using "timed" events makes no sense, because you cannot take the time ;( Thank you for your response.

Comment: Yes, seems unusual they'd not provide a way to do this since the data is being accumulated.  Currently with timed events you can only look at trends of the single event relative to time (i.e. average duration over the past month, duration per session over the past month, duration per user over the past month).  It boggles the mind why on the Event Summary Statistics they'd not simply provide a way to order the events by average duration, duration per session, or duration per user.  Even without a visual graph, just being able to sort the events by these metrics would be useful.